Network setup for a mobile robot base
I am working on a mobile robot base that is supposed to be controlled from a stationary control station. The robot itself has multiple computers onboard, which are on an internal Ethernet network. The control software is distributed accross these devices, and use ROS2 to communicate. The main controller onboard is running Ubuntu server 22.04, and only it connects to the main router, which is on the control station, using several WiFi access points throughout the building. Network configuration is managed by netplan using NetworkManager - NOT networkd - as the backend.
What I'd like to do is have the main controller somehow bridge the two networks without NAT. There is another server on the main network that I can use for this as well.
It ideally should be able to:

Route all traffic including broadcast packets, basically acting identically to a direct Ethernet link between the two, or at least allow ROS2 DDS packets to go through
Use the main router for DHCP
Have minimal latency, though throughput is less important

Basically what I'm looking for is a WiFi client bridge, but the ones I have are bound to a single AP MAC and don't roam at all.
I first tried using netplan to set up a bridge between the WiFi interface and Ethernet, but adding the WiFi interface to a bridge causes it to never become up, somehow. I then set up dnsmasq and iptables to have the main controller act as a seperate DHCP server and NAT router, but this blocks most traffic going through, and does not allow ROS2 nodes to communicate with the main network.
What I have in mind:

Tailscale, as it also allows subnets to be shared over it, but I haven't tested if it lets broadcast packets through, and I think a more lightweight solution should be possible on a local network, as I don't need the traffic to go over the internet.
DHCP relay on the main controller, however this doesn't solve the routing issues. I also haven't been able to get it to work at all, I'm guessing because of the WiFi connection in between.
1 to 1 NAT, but I couldn't find any up-to-date info on how to set one up on Ubuntu.

I've heard IPv6 eliminates the need for NAT, combined with a DHCP relay it may be possible to accomplish this, but I couldn't find anything on how to set up IPv6 routing either. Maybe my Google-fu is lacking.
Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

for such a specialist usage, would Stack Exchange Robotics be a better place to ask your question?

Hello @graham, I'm a moderator at Robotics. This question mentions "robot" twice at the top, and the rest of the post is about configuring a network in Ubuntu. As I read and re-read this post, I'm not sure I understand the intent, but I definitely don't have the depth of Ubuntu networking experience to answer this question. It sounds almost like OP needs a switch or a mesh network, but again I'm no network wizard.

I closed the question at Robotics, as I mentioned there this may be a question best asked at Network Engineering for the mechanism to achieve the requirements, and then potentially a follow-up question here on how to implement that mechanism in Ubuntu. The requirements are driven by the needs of the robotic system, but the problem is a network infrastructure issue.

@Chuck thanks for the clarification

@feoranis idid you do as suggested by Chuck and reach out to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

I initially posted the question there, but it got closed since they only handle enterprise networks. Do you know of any other spaces that this question would fit better? Also, should I have closed this question here and then asked over at Robotics, or would it be considered okay to leave both up?

Looks like it should be SuperUser, sorry.

Yeah, SU seems to be the best fit - just don't say that the computers are actually robots, else you will get re-directed back to Robotics.SE. Just say that they are Linux machines. The fact that they are robots is neither here nor there.

Thanks for the suggestions. Should I close this then?
